# JIRA: Is there a way to force HTTP Basic Authentication with standalone (tomcat) jira?

Tags: http, authentication, tomcat, jira, basic-authentication

We have Jira 5.x running in the standalone variant (embedded tomcat). We'd like to prevent any request without a valid http basic header from reaching the Jira application. Or, in other words, force JIRA to use HTTP Basic authentication. Yes, I know that transmitting http basic credentials over the wire without tls isn't secure and stuff, but we don't have an SSL certificate anyway, so that doesn't matter (it doesn't make it worse than it actually is).

I read that Jira handles HTTP Basic Authentication headers if it gets them, and appending `?os_authType=basic` to the URL makes Jira behave as we wish, but we'd like Jira to enforce HTTP Basic. We wouldn't care if we had some kind of "even-before-jira" login statically configured in tomcat as long as the jira application wouldn't be reachable from outside without it.

Is there a way to achieve this?

I tried adding:

```
<login-config>
  <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
</login-config>
```

to jira's web.xml but that didn't help.

Comment: Since it has to do with Jira itself i think u better try and ask at  [answers.atlassian](http://answers.atlassian.com) too

Comment: Thanks for the good suggestion, Kuf. I did so, here's the Link in case someone with the same issue comes across here: https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/83326/is-there-a-way-to-force-http-basic-authentication-challenges-with-standalone-tomcat-jira